# Ensure a variable is an array, regardless if it is a list or a scalar

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I often find in the situation where I need to be sure that `x` is an array-like object, regardless of whether it comes to me as a float or as a list.

I ultimately need numpy arrays so I expected that np.array() could be a straightforward solution. But actually the brackets still remain a problem.

The bestsolution I have figured out is

```py
def EnsureArray(x):
    if np.isscalar(x):
        return np.array([x])
    else:
        return np.array(np.x)
```

Is it ok, or is there something better (without defining my own function?)

Comment: `np.x` will give an error. Change it to `return np.array(x)`. Otherwise your code is fine. Does it not work as expected?

Comment: “without defining my own function” - you have already defined your own function.  :-)  If `x` is already an `np.array` wouldn’t you just return `x`?  ... unless you’re never expecting the function to receive a numpy array.